# Acceder a un elemento de un XML que no es el del activity_main

Tags: android, android-studio

resulta que tengo un ListView en el main, y dentro de ese ListView otro ListView con su correspondiente xml, me gustaría aplicar un evento al ListView interior desde el main pero tengo problemas a la hora de localizar al elemento, a continuación os muestro

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listV2;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_adapter, null);

        listV2 = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewJugador);

        listV2.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "HOLAAAAAAA?" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

> XML AL QUE QUIERO ACCEDER

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewJugador"...
```

El evento no responde, no hace absolutamente nada

> ACTUALIZACION (El elemento es capturado de forma correcta por medio del Layout inflater pero no reconoce el evento)

```
package com.example.mtx.listviewlugares;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<ciudad> ciudades = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView txt;
    Button bt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ciudades.add(new ciudad(txt.getText().toString()));
                adapterListView adapter = new adapterListView(getApplicationContext(), ciudades);
                ListView listV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
        Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);

       b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a message displayed in a Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView tx =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                tx.setText("LOLLLL");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: pero que quieres hacer exactamente, porque quieres acceder a un listview de otro xml?

Comment: necesito aplicar un evento al listview que esta dentro del listview, me gustaria hacerlo desde el main, pero desde el main solo tengo acceso a los elementos que estan en el xml del main en concreto, necesito cargar un xml ajeno al del main para tener acceso a sus elementos, nose si me he explicado bien

Comment: View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, null);

Comment: el button me lo coge genial pero no me entra al evento, actualizo el post por si puedes echarle un vistazo

Answer (score 1):

no te funciona el OnClickListener porque lo estas seteando en una instancia del layout que nunca se muestra en pantalla. Vos haces esto:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

pero esa vista "v" no la usas luego para mostrarla o agregarla a ningun lugar.

Supongo que dentro del Adapter debes estar usando tambien el layout `row_view`, pero es una instancia distinta a la cual le seteaste el OnClickListener.

Para resolver este problema lo que deberias haces es pasarle el OnClickListener como un parametro a tu adapter:

```
//Instancia este onClickListener dentro del MainActivity:
mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a message displayed in a Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      TextView tx =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
      tx.setText("LOLLLL");
   }
};

//En donde creas el adapter pasale el mOnClickListener como un nuevo parametro
adapterListView adapter = new adapterListView(getApplicationContext(), ciudades, mOnClickListener);
```

Ahora edita el constructor de tu adapter para recibir este OnClickListener:

```
ChatAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ciudad> ciudades,View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener) {
   ...
   //Guarda el mOnClickListener como una propiedad del adapter
   this.mOnClickListener = mOnClickListener;
}
```

Finalmente dentro del Adapter en el onCreateViewHolder setea el OnClickListner a la vista correcta:

```
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent,false);
    Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new MyHolder(item);
}
```

Ademas te recomiendo que empieces con mayusculas el nombre de las clases como `ciudad` o `adapterListView` ya que en minuscula se escriben las instancias.